# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1/(n-1)^{p-1}-1/n^{p-1}}{1/n^p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $p>1$ be a real number, find the limit
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1/(n-1)^{p-1}-1/n^{p-1}}{1/n^p}$$
>   then use this to prove the convergence of $\sum 1/n^p$.

I could solve it only when $p$ is an integer.

The limit above equals to $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{p-1}-1\right]$$

And then use the binomial expansion we got $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} n\left(\binom{p-1}{1}\frac{1}{n-1}+\binom{p-1}{2}\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}+\cdots+\binom{p-1}{p-1}\frac{1}{(n-1)^{p-1}}\right)$$

It's easy to see that above limit is $p-1$.

But I couldn't solve it when $p$ is not an integer, and neither the convergence problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We know
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1/(n-1)^{p-1}-1/n^{p-1}}{1/n^p}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^p(p-1)\int_{n-1}^n\dfrac{1}{x^p}\,dx=(p-1)\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{n-1}^n\left(\dfrac{n}{x}\right)^p\,dx$$
from $n-1\leq x\leq n$ we find $1\leq\dfrac{n}{x}\leq\dfrac{n}{n-1}$ then
$$1\leq\left(\dfrac{n}{x}\right)^p\leq\left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^p$$
integration both sides from $n-1$ to $n$ and then squeeze theorem, gives us the limit equal to $\color{blue}{p-1}$.

This shows the series 
$$\sum_{n=2}\dfrac{1}{(n-1)^{p-1}}-\dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}}$$
which is telescopic so is converge for $p>1$ and [limit comparison test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitComparisonTest.html) shows $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n^p}$ is converge as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q:=1-p$ and $f(x):=(1-x)^q.$ As $n\to+\infty,$

$$\frac{(n-1)^q-n^q}{n^{q-1}}=\frac{f\left(\frac1n\right)-f(0)}{\frac1n}\to f'(0)=-q$$
i.e.
$$\frac{1/(n-1)^{p-1}-1/n^{p-1}}{1/n^p}\to p-1.$$

This allows to apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test): to prove (for $p>1$) that $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ converges, it suffices to check that $\sum\left(1/(n-1)^{p-1}-1/n^{p-1}\right)$ does, which follows from [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).